# Out-projected type in generic interface prohibits the use of metod with generic parameter

Tags: generics, kotlin

I start using Kotlin and I defined interface like this:

```
   interface AAdapter<VH : RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

        fun onCreateAViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup): VH

        fun onBindAViewHolder(v: VH, position: Int)
    }
```

and when I try to use it on code:

```
class Klasa (
        private val adapter: AAdapter<*>
) {

   fun doSth(){
      //... 
      val vh = this.adapter.onCreateAViewHolder(parent)
      //on below line I get error
      adapter.onBindAViewHolder(v, position)
     //...
  }

}
```

I get error that  **Out-projected type 'AAdapter<*>' prohibits the use of 'public abstract fun onBindAViewHolder(v: T, position: Int): Unit**

I tied to add "in" or "out" to definition but I'm confused.

How to allow it.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `AAdapter<*>` with `AAdapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>`.

```
class Klasa (
        private val adapter: AAdapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
) {
 // ...
```

Because you have declared that `AAdapter` has a type parameter `VH` whose type is any subclass of `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`. And in the class `Klasa` you have an instance of `AAdapter` which has type parameter of any type.